# Client moved to new host, admin assets returning 404 error

Tags: control-panel, javascript, admin

Client has moved their site to a new host and now the back-end/control panel assets are throwing a 404 error. For example,

- `/admin.php?S=ca55e292a4e770d2f3a83253f0027950&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&plugin=ee_interact.event,ee_broadcast.event,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_toggle_all,ee_navigation&file=json2,underscore,cp/global_start&v=1463044170`,
- `/admin.php?S=ca55e292a4e770d2f3a83253f0027950&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&file=cp/global_end&v=1463044000`, etc.

I can login to `/admin` but none of the links, menu etc are navigable due to above issue. Site is fine locally and on previous host but now throwing errors and no idea what is causing this problem. Any suggestions on debugging appreciated.

Comment: further to above, digging a bit deeper and now if I turn debug to 1 in index.php (was 0) the site fails to load?!?

Comment: are you sure all paths are set correctly? especially server paths to the themes directory?